# Does Linux spin_lock_irqsave() disables ARM FIQ interrupt?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, spinlock, fiq

I am writing a Linux device driver and need to serialize access to critical sections of the driver from tasks and interrupts. I am developing for ARM.

If I use **`spin_lock_irqsave()`** and **`spin_unlock_irqrestore()`** pair to protect my critical sections, is FIQ blocked while in these critical sections?

I tried looking at the implementations of these 2 functions, in particular **`spin_lock_irqsave()`**. My initial impression is that FIQ is not disabled. Just want to verify this with the experts out here.

Please enlighten me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think Linux uses FIQ, so an FIQ will not conflict with a Linux ISR.  That said, I believe it uses:

```
cpsid i
```

This disables regular interrupts.  To also disable FIQs it would need to do

```
cpsid if
```

See: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/arch/arm/include/asm/irqflags.h#L25

Comment: Hi @stark, just to clarify, I am of the same opinion that Linux most probably do not use FIQ but the code base I am working on uses the FIQ for its own purpose. This FIQ calls into my driver code.

Comment: If you need to disable FIQ, you could do your own custom irq_save.

Comment: ... but watch out for race conditions in the order of disable/enable.